# Rounding off GST value in AX 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I want to round off the ***GST value*** in ***Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009***,
Any idea how can i do that, and is there any ***hotfix update for AX 2009*** for GST Configuration recently.

Comment: What is GST, and in what context do want to round it? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps MST (money standard something)?
Rounding is relatively easy in Ax 2009

But there are quite a few ways of doing it..

You can try by making a job and try this.. :)

```
ABCPercentA value = 3.1234567;
;

info(num2str(roundUp(value, 0.01),1,10,1,1));
info(num2str(round(value, 0.001),1,8,1,1));
info(num2str(roundDown(value, 0.0001),1,6,1,1));
info(num2str(round(value, 0.0001),1,4,1,1));
info(num2str(round(value, 0.01),1,2,1,1));
```

The results are:

```
Message (18:31:20)
3.1300000000
3.12300000
3.123400
3.1235
3.12
```